# LaTeXTools in SublimeText: quickly open subfiles

Tags: latexmk, sublime-text

I have started using LaTeXTools in SublimeText and think it is amazing! I am wondering if there is a convenient way to open subfiles from a master file, like I can with the *Structure* sidebar in Texmaker. For example, if my `thesis.tex` file contains `\input{introduction}`, is there a way to open the `introduction.tex` file without going into my file explorer and double-clicking on it?

Answer (score 1):

A very quick help could be to drop the whole folder containing all your files of your thesis into ST. The structure will then be visible on the sidebar and you are able to switch quickly between each subfile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.